# ORO - Elasticsearch datagrid query string `endsWith` expression

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I've been working on applying additional filters into `datagrids` based on `Oro\Bundle\SearchBundle\Datagrid\Datasource\SearchDatasource` in `ORO - 4.1.2`.
In case when search engine based on DB, search expressions applied properly, especially for ones like:

```
Oro\Bundle\SearchBundle\Query\Criteria\Criteria::expr()->startsWith($field, $value);
Oro\Bundle\SearchBundle\Query\Criteria\Criteria::expr()->endsWith($field, $value);
```

In case when `elasticsearch` used, the search expression `startsWith` applied properly,
converts in `prefix` query filter. But, `endsWith` expressions just ignored, don`t convert in` elasticsearch` query.

Should I apply some different expressions to get `endsWith` results?
Is it an issue of `OroElasticSearchBundle`?

Answer (score 1):

Oro Search Engine doesn't support the `endsWith` operator because it's not widely used for the search.

Another reason it's not implemented is a bad performance of the ElasticSearch wildcard in regular fields. This issue was recently solved in ES 7.9. Because OroCommerce depends on 7.0+ it will not be implemented in the core for 4.1 LTS.

If you want to implement it in the customization, you can create a where part builder to support the "ends_with" operator using a wildcard query.

You can also contribute the solution to the core Github repository if you want this to be enabled in the next LTS.  For more details, see [How to Contribute to the OroCommerce Source Code](https://doc.oroinc.com/community/#contribute-to-the-source-code-translations-and-documentation)